# Member registration in Zoo Visitor with CartThrob checkout form

Tags: cartthrob, zoo-visitor

I am using CartThrob for e-commerce part and Zoo Visitor for managing members.

We know that with the CartThrob checkout form, new member registration is being done. Its working fine in my case and member has been created but no member entry is being created in Zoo Visitor channel.

I hope, someone faced such a problem and can share some pointer to me.

Thanks,

Comment: MightyBigRobot (the makers of CartThrob) have their variation of ZooVisitor called Profile:Edit that integrates with CartThrob

Comment: Thanks Justin. Yes, I came to know about Profile:Edit later but I had already done most with ZooVisitor. Due to tight schedule I wouldn't like to install and implement Profile:Edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how good integration is for the two at this point but I think you still need to submit via hidden input fields for Zoo Visitor within the Cartthrob checkout. If you're using a two-step checkout process it's easier because you can have one page for the member fields submitted as a Zoo Visitor entry and then the other page for Billing/Shipping fields etc for Cartthrob.

If that doesn't fit into your workflow then you could always use AJAX form submission to post and fill in hidden fields on the page.

What does your current code look like?

Comment: Thanks Ian, I 'm using CT's checkout_form tag with member registration fields. After much investigation, I didn't get any proper solution so developed an extension which is working fine.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's any seamless integration there yet, much to the pity. Sounds like an interesting extension however. Are you planning to make this available? I may have need for something similar very soon.